# GroupBy and Store and repeat

Tags: node.js, mongodb

(Node js mongoDb)
I have an array of objects in

> Abc table

```
data[{valu:123,tag:"model"},
{value:456,tag:"test"},
{value:789,tag:"test"},
{valu:143,tag:"mode"l},
{value:556,tag:"test2"},
{value:589,tag:"test2"}]
```

I have to sum them based on the tag name and store in same table. For each tag there is parent tag in

> tag table

```
{name:"model",ptag:''},
{name:"test",ptag:"model"},
{name:"test2",ptag:"test"}
```

i want to marge and store them based on parent tag untill it has no parent!!
please help in this....

Comment: Are you using ODM like mongoose?

Comment: yes  @ShamsNahid